# jQuery - not selecting a class that begins with 'tinymce'

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What is wrong with this code:

```
$('input[maxlength],textarea[maxlength]').not("[class^='tinymce']").each(function() {
```

I am trying to select:

- all `<textarea>`s with an `attr` `maxlength`
- which don't have a class name that begins with "*tinymce*"

Comment: [Nothing wrong](http://jsfiddle.net/9s3Jz/), check your markup.

Comment: No error it just doesn't read the not part

Comment: Does your code look like this `$('input[maxlength],textarea[maxlength]').not("[class^='tinymce']").each(function(){/*CODE HERE*/});`

Comment: It must be something wrong with your HTML structure, or these items are created AFTER this is ran

Comment: What goes wrong? Doesn't it select all elements? Does it select no elements? Does it select the wrong elements? **What's going wrong?**

Comment: Maybe you're accidentally `return`-ing from the function? Just guessing; some code would be helpful.

Comment: Give the code inside the `function(){}`

Comment: *No error it just doesn't read the not part* - Ah, I missed this comment. You mean it **does** select elements which class starts with `tinymce`, right?

Comment: When using class starts with, it only looks at the first class applied to that element. If the element has multiple classes, this selector can become unpredictable.

Comment: [Small test which doesn't require you to open your console.](http://jsfiddle.net/xJCCT/2/)

Comment: Oooops it was cached in my browser, sorry for the false alarm

Comment: [How to disable cache using the](http://i45.tinypic.com/k3swhu.png) [Web Developer](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) [extension](http://i45.tinypic.com/k3swhu.png)

Comment: yeah I have this although turn it off yesterday when I need to test the caching performance. Forgot all about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works for me...

http://jsfiddle.net/xJCCT/1/

Only one "hello" is outputted.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to start with `tinymce` or just contain the class `tinymce`?

```
​$('input,textarea').filter(function(){
    return(!$(this).hasClass('tinymce'));
}).filter(function(){
    return($(this).attr(​​​​​​​​​​​​'maxlength'));
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fqg5Y/1/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/z5Wsk/

this code selects the textareas that don't have a class which begins with "tinymce".

```
$('input[maxlength],textarea[maxlength]').filter(function() {
    if($(this).attr('class')) {
        return null == $(this).attr('class').match(/\btinymce[a-z0-9_\-]*\b/i);
    }
    return true;
}).each(function() {
    //your part
});
```

​example: an element with `class="another tinymceFOO"` is not selected (while the accepted answer would select it).